# Extracting contents inside <script type="text/javascript"> and $(function ()

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on scraping data from websites. I was able to extract contents inside the tag . But it has '$(function () {' inside it. I want to extract contents inside it.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json 
url = 'https://www.broadwayinbound.com/shows/'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()      # a `bytes` object
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
results = soup.findAll('script', {'type':'text/javascript'})
r = []
for result in results :
    if 'var shows = [' in result.text:
        r.append(result.text)
print (r[0])
```

I want to extract the contents of 'var shows' alone.

```
{"Id":"12680","ClientClassCode":"default","ShowName":"Ain't Too Proud - The Life and Times of The Temptations","ShowCode":"AINTPROUD","SortName":"Ain't Too Proud - The Life and Times of The Temptations","ShowLogo":"/product-resources/Aint-Too-Proud-Temptations-Musical-Broadway-Group-Sales-Show-Tickets-500-102318.jpg","ShowLogoText":"Ain't Too Proud - The Life and Times of The Temptations Tickets | Broadway......
```

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: In this website [view-source:https://www.broadwayinbound.com/shows/] , i need to extract the contents inside **var shows**.

Comment: Please read **[ask]** and then create a **[mcve]** to demonstrate the problem you have.  Don't just post your code and say *"I want it to do xyz"*.  Help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rest of the code works, a simple regex should do the trick :)

```py
import urllib.request
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.broadwayinbound.com/shows/'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()      # a `bytes` object
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
results = soup.findAll('script', {'type':'text/javascript'})
r = []
for result in results :
    if 'var shows = [' in result.text:
        x = re.findall(r"var shows = (\[.*\])", result.text)
        if (len(x) > 0):
            r.append(x[0])

print(json.loads(r[0]))
print(json.loads(r[0])[0]["Id"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manipulate the string. Essentially it gives you a list of json structures:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json 

url = 'https://www.broadwayinbound.com/shows/'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text     # a `bytes` object
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
results = soup.findAll('script', {'type':'text/javascript'})
r = []


for result in results :
    if 'var shows = [' in result.text:
        jsonStr = result.text

        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('var shows = [')[1]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit('];',1)[0]

        jsonStr_list = jsonStr.split('{"Id":')[1:]

        for each in jsonStr_list:
            each = jsonStr_list[0]
            w=1
            if each[-1] == ',':
                each = each.rstrip(',')

            jsonTemp = '{"Id":' + each
            jsonObj = json.loads(jsonTemp)

            r.append(jsonObj)
```

**Output:**

```
print (r)
[{'Id': '12680', 'ClientClassCode': 'default', 'ShowName': "Ain't Too Proud - The Life and Times of The Temptations", 'ShowCode': 'AINTPROUD', 'SortName': "Ain't Too Proud - The Life and Times of The Temptations", 'ShowLogo': '/product-resources/Aint-Too-Proud-Temptations-Musical-Broadway-Group-Sales-Show-Tickets-500-102318.jpg', 'ShowLogoText': "Ain't Too Proud - The Life and Times of The Temptations Tickets | Broadway Inbound", 'ShowPromo': '', 'ShowPromoText': '', 'Description': "<em>Ain't Too Proud</em> is the electrifying new musical that follows The Temptations' extraordinary journey from the streets of Detroit to the Rock & Roll Hall of Fame.<br /><br />Five guys. One dream. And a sound that would make music history. With their signature dance moves and unmistakable harmonies, they rose to the top of the charts creating an amazing 42 Top Ten Hits with 14 reaching number one. The rest is history — how they met, the groundbreaking heights they hit, and how personal and political conflicts threatened to tear the group apart as the United States fell into civil unrest. This thrilling story of brotherhood, family, loyalty, and betrayal is set to the beat of the group's treasured hits, including “My Girl,” “Just My Imagination,” “Get Ready,” “Papa Was a Rolling Stone,” and so many more.<br /><br />After breaking house records at Berkeley Rep, The Kennedy Center, and at the Ahmanson Theater, <em>Ain't Too Proud</em>, written by three time Obie Award winner Dominique Morisseau, directed by two-time Tony Award® winner Des McAnuff (<em>Jersey Boys</em>), and featuring choreography by Tony nominee Sergio Trujillo (<em>Jersey Boys</em>, <em>On Your Feet</em>), now brings the untold story of this legendary quintet to irresistible life on Broadway.", 'Category': 'Broadway', 'CategoryCode': 'BW', 'ShowType': 'Musical', 'ShowTypeCode': 'MUSICAL', 'Rating': 'Might not be suitable for younger children', 'RatingCode': 'PT', 'City': 'New York', 'CityCode': 'NYCA', 'FirstPerformance': '2/28/2019', 'NextPerformance': '5/30/2019', 'NextPerformanceTime': '7:00 PM', 'OnSaleThrough': '6/7/2020', 'Weekdays': ['fr', 'mo', 'sa', 'su', 'th', 'tu', 'we'], 'MinPrice': '42.00', 'MaxPrice': '385.90', 'GroupMinimum': '10', 'MaximumTickets': '25', 'VenueName': 'Imperial Theatre', 'Url': '/shows/aint-too-proud-the-life-and-times-of-the-temptations/', 'BroadwayCollectionEN': 'http://www.broadwaycollection.com/shows/https://www.broadwaycollection.com/shows/aint-too-proud/', 'BroadwayCollectionES': 'http://www.broadwaycollection.com/es/shows/https://www.broadwaycollection.com/es/shows/aint-too-proud/', 'BroadwayCollectionDE': 'http://www.broadwaycollection.com/de/shows/https://www.broadwaycollection.com/de/shows/aint-too-proud/', 'BroadwayCollectionJA': 'http://www.broadwaycollection.com/ja/shows/https://www.broadwaycollection.com/ja/shows/aint-too-proud/', 'BroadwayCollectionPT': 'http://www.broadwaycollection.com/pt-br/shows/https://www.broadwaycollection.com/pt-br/shows/aint-too-proud/', 'BroadwayCollectionZH': 'http://www.broadwaycollection.com/zh-hans/shows/https://www.broadwaycollection.com/zh-hans/shows/aint-too-proud/', 'RunTime': '2 hours and 30 minutes, including intermission', 'ShowLetUsKnow': False}, {'Id': '12680', 'ClientClassCode': 'default', 'ShowName': "Ain't Too Proud - The Life and Times of The Temptations", 'ShowCode': 'AINTPROUD', 'SortName': "Ain't Too Proud - The Life and Times of The Temptations", 'ShowLogo': '/product-resources/Aint-Too-Proud-Temptations-Musical-Broadway-Group-Sales-Show-Tickets-500-102318.jpg', 'ShowLogoText': "Ain't Too Proud - The Life and Times of The Temptations Tickets | Broadway Inbound", 'ShowPromo': '', 'ShowPromoText': '', 'Description': "<em>Ain't Too Proud</em> is the electrifying new musical that follows The Temptat ...
```